# GIT - error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, backup

Im very new to GIT and have been using it to take backups of my server. Previously i've had no issues, backups have been appearing over in gitlab. Today I've tried and receive this:

```
$ git push -u origin master

Counting objects: 8664, done. 
warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
Compressing objects: 100% (5771/5771), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 266790794 bytes)
remote: fatal: early EOF
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:XXX/server-XXX.git'
```

If you have any advice please let me know in the comments (keep in mind i'm very new to GIT) thanks!

Comment: How much is the size of commit files?

Comment: Have you tried after restarting your PC? or maybe closing applications that consume lots of memory.

Comment: If any of your file > 50MB then you should check the following link

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/